# What is the meaning of this message in IDA?

Tags: ida, hexrays

What is the meaning of this mmessage in IDA:

> The decompiler assumes that the segment '.text' is read-only because of its NAME. All data references to the segment will be replaced by constant values. This may lead to drastic changes in the decompiler output. If the segment is not read-only, please change the segment NAME.

How can we fix this issue in IDA Pro?

Comment: It's not an issue and it does not need to be fixed. Only if you are experiencing issues with the decompilation should you take the advice given in the message (or the reply below).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of this message in IDA?

When you load a file into Ida (.exe, ⁣.dll, ⁣.bin,,.hex, etc.), it creates at least one segment for the memory address (you can add or remove segments on your own). Every segment has a unique name that you can change. A segment with the name .text means that the content of this segment is read-only and not writable. So if a piece of code is accessing this segment and changing a variable value in it, the message in your question will appear and say that the target segment is **considered** read-only, which results in wrong decompiled code.

> How can we fix this issue in IDA Pro?

Two workarounds:

1. Change the `segment name` to something else: <kbd>View</kbd>-><kbd>Open</kbd> <kbd>subviews</kbd>-><kbd>Segments</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>), right click on the segment-->Edit, Change the name.
2. Change the `segment permission` to read and write: Follow the above path and check the `write` and `read` check boxes.